# UX Design: Tabs vs Radio for changing views of same information

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, user-experience

We have an applciation where the user can view configuration information about an app. The configurations are a list of properites - each with: key, value, and category.

We are debating between using tabs or radio buttons to swtich between viewing the normal and advanced view of the configs.

Example [Normal]:

```
Memory for App - 5MB
Persistant Storage - 5GB
My Awesome Varaible - abc
```

Example [Advanced]:

```
app.memory - 5 - SYS_PARAM
app.storage - 5 - SYS_PARAM
my.awesome.var - abc - USER_PARAM
```

Is there a standard for using tabs or radio or some other selector for changing between the views/modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard on Google's Material Design. Many of these can be applied in general to projects without embracing every aspect of Material Design.

They have done a great job of standardizing use of controls. Tabs have always meant switching between different views of the same information, though they have not always been implemented that way. https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html

Radio buttons are intended as a way of selecting one item from a set, though I've been guilty of using them to switch views too. 
https://material.google.com/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-checkbox

If you want to follow a known standard, there it is.

Your project may have other constraints that would make using tabs unreasonable. That said, if you can spare the space, and don't mind introducing a new navigational element to the page, then definitely use tabs.